# Fetch Database table data and paste into other Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch data from oracle database and paste complete table data into separate excel sheet.
I tried below code but getting error like "subscript out of range" Please help.

```
sFilewithPath = "c:/data/file.xlsx"

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Workbooks.Open(sFilewithPath).Activate
        Workbooks(sFilewithPath).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If
```

I am getting error in line where I am pasting data from rs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why you get the error (explanation only)

The `Workbooks(sFilewithPath)` does not work with the full path but only the file name `Workbooks(sFileNameOnly)`. Anyway I highly recommend to use the method below instead:

#### Solution

Use this to open your workbook and reference it to a variable `MyWb`

```
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(sFilewithPath)
```

Thes use this variable to access your opened worbook

```
MyWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Don't forget to close your workbook in the end or it will stay open.

```
MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: That worksheet is not available in same folder. That's why i have given full path. If full path not mentioned then how  the data will added to that file (sFilewithPath)

Comment: @Mehul Check my answer again `Workbooks.Open` needs the full path of course but the `Workbooks(sFileNameOnly)` only works with the file name (without path) then. Did you try what I have suggested in the second part of my anwser? This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. code is working fine. I have updated code with SaveChanges:=True.